# Error while exporting objective c code to Android

Tags: android, objective-c, apportable

I used apportable to export my objective c code into android device but i get following error:-

```
command failed: /Users/ibrahimissawi/.apportable/SDK/toolchain/macosx/ninja/ninja --no-strip-ansi-escapes -j 4 /Users/ibrahimissawi/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/LetterRingSound/LetterRingSound-debug.apk
```

Comment: iam using the free trial

Comment: look higher up in the build output log

Answer (score -1):

this error means you maybe have some warning in your code. such as a in a non-void function,you dont return a bool value. please check the detailed error info in terminal.